# Wordpress disqus comment count.js doesn't update in realtime

Tags: javascript, wordpress, comments, disqus

I have integrated disqus plugin in wordpress & i need to show comment count on top of the page.I have used count.js for it.

```
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//xyz.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

But count updates after 20 minutes on top. Though it shows correct count & comment in disqus comment embed but not through count.js.

How can I show updated comment count in realtime .Why does it take 20 min to update ?